# General purpose 2D grid

Tags: beginner, reinventing-the-wheel, rust, vectors

I am developing (WIP) a mine sweeping game to get more familiar with Rust.
I decided to represent the mine field as a 2D grid.
While developing I realized that this grid can be outsourced as a general purpose grid into an [own module](https://github.com/conqp/grid).
Here it goes:

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Grid<T> {
    width: usize,
    height: usize,
    items: Vec<Vec<T>>,
}

impl<T> Grid<T> {
    pub fn new(width: usize, height: usize, initializer: impl Fn() -> T) -> Self {
        Self {
            width,
            height,
            items: (0..height)
                .map(move |_| (0..width).map(|_| initializer()).collect())
                .collect(),
        }
    }

    pub fn width(&self) -> usize {
        self.width
    }

    pub fn height(&self) -> usize {
        self.height
    }

    pub fn get(&self, x: usize, y: usize) -> Option<&T> {
        if x < self.width() && y < self.height() {
            Some(&self.items[y][x])
        } else {
            None
        }
    }

    pub fn get_mut(&mut self, x: usize, y: usize) -> Option<&mut T> {
        if x < self.width() && y < self.height() {
            Some(&mut self.items[y][x])
        } else {
            None
        }
    }

    pub fn iter(&self) -> impl Iterator<Item = &T> {
        self.items.iter().flat_map(|line| line)
    }

    pub fn iter_mut(&mut self) -> impl Iterator<Item = &mut T> {
        self.items.iter_mut().flat_map(|line| line)
    }

    pub fn enumerate(&self) -> impl Iterator<Item = (usize, usize, &T)> {
        self.items
            .iter()
            .enumerate()
            .flat_map(|(y, line)| line.iter().enumerate().map(move |(x, item)| (x, y, item)))
    }

    pub fn enumerate_mut(&mut self) -> impl Iterator<Item = (usize, usize, &mut T)> {
        self.items.iter_mut().enumerate().flat_map(|(y, line)| {
            line.iter_mut()
                .enumerate()
                .map(move |(x, item)| (x, y, item))
        })
    }

    pub fn neighbors(&self, x: usize, y: usize) -> impl Iterator<Item = (usize, usize, &T)> {
        self.enumerate().filter(move |(other_x, other_y, _)| {
            is_neighbor(other_x.abs_diff(x), other_y.abs_diff(y))
        })
    }

    pub fn neighbors_mut(
        &mut self,
        x: usize,
        y: usize,
    ) -> impl Iterator<Item = (usize, usize, &mut T)> {
        self.enumerate_mut().filter(move |(other_x, other_y, _)| {
            is_neighbor(other_x.abs_diff(x), other_y.abs_diff(y))
        })
    }
}

fn is_neighbor(dx: usize, dy: usize) -> bool {
    is_adjunct(dx) && is_adjunct(dy) && !same_field(dx, dy)
}

fn is_adjunct(offset: usize) -> bool {
    offset == 0 || offset == 1
}

fn same_field(dx: usize, dy: usize) -> bool {
    dx == 0 && dy == 0
}
```

As I am still a beginner regarding Rust, I'd like to have feedback on the proper and idiomatic use of the language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code is already of utterly high quality for a "beginner" in Rust. I think you should be proud of yourself here!

Highlights:

- you use an initializer function in the constructor!
- your code is generic over all types, and you use `impl` types where possible
- your code is free of panics
- you have tests for the important items

Here's what I would improve.

---

**Linting**

Use clippy to lint your code. It's the default for Rust.

The first "warning" is `clippy::len_without_is_empty`, which normally applies to vectors, and warns if a struct has a `len(&self) -> usize` method without an `is_empty(&self) -> bool` method. Since the length of your array is not variable, but constant after initialization, I would rename the method to something else to avoid associating your `len` with variable-length objects.

```rust
pub fn size(&self) -> usize {
    self.width * self.height
}
```

Then you have a `clippy::flat_map_identity` lint. Your `iter` and `iter_mut` methods make use of `flat_map`, which combines `flatten()` and `map()` in one function. You do not need the `map` part, since you do not apply any function to `row`. So you can shorten that to `flatten()`.

```rust
pub fn iter(&self) -> impl Iterator<Item = &T> {
    self.items.iter().flatten()
}

pub fn iter_mut(&mut self) -> impl Iterator<Item = &mut T> {
    self.items.iter_mut().flatten()
}
```

---

**Finding neighbors**

Your `fn neighbors(...) -> impl Iterator` is very inefficient, since you traverse the whole `Grid` to find the neighbors, whose coordinates you could calculate very easily instead. Calculating the coordinates directly is a constant-time operation, while your current implementation is `O(n * m)` where n and m are the height and width of your grid.

I would write this with slightly more code, but in a more efficient manner. Unfortunately, we need to convert between usize and isize a couple of times then.

```rust
const NEIGHBOR_INDICES: [isize; 3] = [-1, 0, 1];

..... // impl Grid

pub fn neighbors(&self, x: usize, y: usize) -> impl Iterator<Item = (usize, usize, &T)> {
    self.calc_neighbor_indices(x, y)
        .map(|(x, y)| (x, y, self.get(x, y).unwrap()))
}

fn generate_neighbor_offsets() -> impl Iterator<Item = (isize, isize)> {
    NEIGHBOR_INDICES
        .into_iter()
        .flat_map(|i| [i].into_iter().cycle().zip(NEIGHBOR_INDICES))
        .filter(|(x, y)| !(*x == 0 && *y == 0))
}

fn calc_neighbor_indices(&self, x: usize, y: usize) -> impl Iterator<Item = (usize, usize)> + '_ {
    Self::generate_neighbor_offsets()
        .map(move |(nx, ny)| (x as isize + nx, y as isize + ny))
        .filter(|(nx, ny)| {
            // remove elements outside of grid
            0 <= *nx && *nx < self.width as isize && 0 <= *ny && *ny < self.height as isize
        })
        .map(|(nx, ny)| (nx as usize, ny as usize))
}
```

I was surprised to find out that `neighbors_mut()` cannot be written in the same manner, but I cannot figure out right now how to fix it. So this **does not** work.

```rust
pub fn neighbors_mut(
    &mut self,
    x: usize,
    y: usize,
) -> impl Iterator<Item = (usize, usize, &mut T)> {
    self.calc_neighbor_indices(x, y)
        .map(|(x, y)| (x, y, self.get_mut(x, y).unwrap()))
}
```

If you could figure out how to write that correctly, you could get rid of the `is_adjunct()` and `is_neighbor()` functions.

---

**data structure**

You have decided to represent the 2D grid as a `Vec<Vec<T>>`, which is the trivial solution, but by far not the most efficient.

AFAICR allocating a new `Vec` reserves space for one element. If that space is used, and you want to push another element to the vector, the current size is doubled. So the vector grows exponentially, which is good for the runtime performance, but slow for allocation. Generally, think that each row requires `ld(width)` allocations, where `ld` is the binary logarithm. Furthermore, the same considerations apply to your outer vector. So you are looking at a total of `ld(height) * ld(width)` allocations (assuming no optimizations). BUT, since you used `collect()`, which uses `FromIterator`, the vector automatically is allocated with the right capacity from the size hint of the iterator, so you wouldn't need to worry about that here.

Now you have an outer vector which stores the starting address of each row vector, so you have `height + 1` vectors. Since they are allocated individually, they are very likely located at different positions on the heap. That is bad for performance, since when you need the data, the CPU needs to "jump" to different addresses often. This is not critical for your envisioned minesweeper, but nevertheless good to keep in mind.

What I would do here is storing the data as 1D-vector internally, and then calculating the offsets in the vector from a provided x and y. This is often done in numerical applications, where performance is of highest importance.

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Grid<T> {
    width: usize,
    height: usize,
    items: Vec<T>,
}

impl<T> Grid<T> {
    pub fn new(width: usize, height: usize, initializer: impl Fn() -> T) -> Self {
        Self {
            width,
            height,
            items: (0..height)
                .flat_map(|_| (0..width).map(|_| initializer()))
                .collect(),
        }
    }


    pub fn get(&self, x: usize, y: usize) -> Option<&T> {
        if x < self.width() && y < self.height() {
            Some(&self.items[self.coordinate_to_idx(x, y)])
        } else {
            None
        }
    }

    pub fn get_mut(&mut self, x: usize, y: usize) -> Option<&mut T> {
        if x < self.width() && y < self.height() {
            let idx = self.coordinate_to_idx(x, y);
            Some(&mut self.items[idx])
        } else {
            None
        }
    }

    fn idx_to_coordinate(&self, idx: usize) -> (usize, usize) {
        let x = idx % self.width;
        let y = (idx - x) / self.width;
        (x, y)
    }


    fn coordinate_to_idx(&self, x: usize, y: usize) -> usize {
        y * self.width + x
    }
```

Then you can also remove the `flatten()` call in `iter`. Unfortunately, the `iter_mut` method has the same issue as `neighbors_mut`. Maybe someone else can figure that out. I have commented it out for now, to make the code compile.

Here is my final code. Please apologize that I could not get it to work entirely.

```rust
const NEIGHBOR_INDICES: [isize; 3] = [-1, 0, 1];

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Grid<T> {
    width: usize,
    height: usize,
    items: Vec<T>,
}

impl<T> Grid<T> {
    pub fn new(width: usize, height: usize, initializer: impl Fn() -> T) -> Self {
        Self {
            width,
            height,
            items: (0..height)
                .flat_map(|_| (0..width).map(|_| initializer()))
                .collect(),
        }
    }

    pub fn width(&self) -> usize {
        self.width
    }

    pub fn height(&self) -> usize {
        self.height
    }

    pub fn size(&self) -> usize {
        self.width * self.height
    }

    pub fn get(&self, x: usize, y: usize) -> Option<&T> {
        if x < self.width() && y < self.height() {
            Some(&self.items[self.coordinate_to_idx(x, y)])
        } else {
            None
        }
    }

    fn coordinate_to_idx(&self, x: usize, y: usize) -> usize {
        y * self.width + x
    }

    pub fn get_mut(&mut self, x: usize, y: usize) -> Option<&mut T> {
        if x < self.width() && y < self.height() {
            let idx = self.coordinate_to_idx(x, y);
            Some(&mut self.items[idx])
        } else {
            None
        }
    }

    pub fn iter(&self) -> impl Iterator<Item = &T> {
        self.items.iter()
    }

    pub fn iter_mut(&mut self) -> impl Iterator<Item = &mut T> {
        self.items.iter_mut()
    }

    pub fn enumerate(&self) -> impl Iterator<Item = (usize, usize, &T)> {
        self.items.iter().enumerate().map(|(idx, item)| {
            let (x, y) = self.idx_to_coordinate(idx);
            (x, y, item)
        })
    }

    // pub fn enumerate_mut(&mut self) -> impl Iterator<Item = (usize, usize, &mut T)> {
    //     self.items.iter_mut().enumerate().map(|(idx, item)| {
    //         let (x, y) = self.idx_to_coordinate(idx);
    //         (x, y, item)
    //     })
    // }

    fn idx_to_coordinate(&self, idx: usize) -> (usize, usize) {
        let x = idx % self.width;
        let y = (idx - x) / self.width;
        (x, y)
    }

    pub fn neighbors(&self, x: usize, y: usize) -> impl Iterator<Item = (usize, usize, &T)> {
        self.calc_neighbor_indices(x, y)
            .map(|(x, y)| (x, y, self.get(x, y).unwrap()))
    }

    fn generate_neighbor_offsets() -> impl Iterator<Item = (isize, isize)> {
        NEIGHBOR_INDICES
            .into_iter()
            .flat_map(|i| [i].into_iter().cycle().zip(NEIGHBOR_INDICES))
            .filter(|(x, y)| !(*x == 0 && *y == 0))
    }

    fn calc_neighbor_indices(
        &self,
        x: usize,
        y: usize,
    ) -> impl Iterator<Item = (usize, usize)> + '_ {
        Self::generate_neighbor_offsets()
            .map(move |(nx, ny)| (x as isize + nx, y as isize + ny))
            .filter(|(nx, ny)| {
                // remove elements outside of grid
                0 <= *nx && *nx < self.width as isize && 0 <= *ny && *ny < self.height as isize
            })
            .map(|(nx, ny)| (nx as usize, ny as usize))
    }

    // pub fn neighbors_mut(
    //     &mut self,
    //     x: usize,
    //     y: usize,
    // ) -> impl Iterator<Item = (usize, usize, &mut T)> {
    //     self.enumerate_mut().filter(move |(other_x, other_y, _)| {
    //         is_neighbor(other_x.abs_diff(x), other_y.abs_diff(y))
    //     })
    // }
}

fn is_neighbor(dx: usize, dy: usize) -> bool {
    is_adjunct(dx) && is_adjunct(dy) && !same_field(dx, dy)
}

fn is_adjunct(offset: usize) -> bool {
    offset == 0 || offset == 1
}

fn same_field(dx: usize, dy: usize) -> bool {
    dx == 0 && dy == 0
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I think regarding `neighbors_mut`, you borrow self first immutable and then mutable, which is not allowed. You probably can first put `self.calc_neighbor_indices()` into a temporary variable and then operate on it. I will test this tomorrow.

Comment: Regarding the implementation with one single linear Vec, I will probably use this one, since it'll make the code easier and since the external interface is not affected by this implementation detail.